# Meteor.js and non shuffling each

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a problem implementing a non shuffling each over a reactive collection.
With this I mean that I have a collection ordered by a score value, and I don't want to change the order even if a score change.
I'd like it to be reactive but without the list items changing position every time.

The current code is this

```
ListController = FastRender.RouteController.extend({
find: function (tag){
    if(!!tag){
        return Lib.Items.Tags.SupportedType[tag].find;
    }
    return {};
},
findOptions: function(order, pageNum) {
    var findOption = { limit: Lib.Items.Settings.ItemsPerPage * (parseInt(pageNum) || this.increment)};
    if(!!order){
        _.extend(findOption, Lib.Items.ListOrders.SupportedType[order].findOption);
    }
    return findOption;
},
waitOn: function() {
    return [
        Meteor.subscribe('items.all', this.params.tag, this.params.order, this.pageNum),
    ];
},
data: function () {
    return {
        "items": Items.find(this.find(), this.findOptions(this.params.order, this.params.pageNum))
    };
},
action: function(){
    this.render();
}
});
[...]

this.route('list', {
    path: '/list/:pageNum?',
    controller: ListController
});
this.route('list_order_limit', {
    path: '/list/order/:order/:pageNum?',
    controller: ListController
});
this.route('list_tag_limit', {
    path: '/list/tag/:tag/:pageNum?',
    controller: ListController
});
this.route('list_tag_order_limit', {
    path: '/list/tag/:tag/order/:order/:pageNum?',
    controller: ListController
});
```

and

```
{{#each items}}
        {{> item}}
{{/each}}
```

With this everything works but the list change orders (which is correct but not the behaviour I'd like).
I tried some different solutions but nothing worked.
I started by modifying the data.
I put

```
data: function () {
return {
    "items": Items.find(this.find(), this.findOptions(this.params.pageNum))
};
},
```

In this way the data knows nothing about the ordering (only the subscription knows about which order is used to take the first *number of items* items).
The problem is that in this way even if the route change from one ordering to another the list is not updated. And while this happens I see the subscription getting called with the new order parameter (so the data sent via ddp should actually be correct).
I even tried stopping and resubscribing but nothing changed.
What I'm doing wrong? Is there a better way to have a list reactive in its item but not in its order?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything in your code that explicitly references the order by the score value; however I believe this is an unresolved issue in Meteor: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1276.

One of the workarounds suggested in that thread was to add an explicit sort by `_id` on the client, which will ensure that the cursor is stable even when items change.

I can imagine a more unconventional way to work around this, which is to compute the desired order in the publish function and use the [publish API](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_publish) to send custom fields over to the client, and then sorting by these fields. This is more complicated than a cursor but will result in the items showing up in the exact order determined at publish time.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to include the sorting methods in the lib.
Anyway, I used your last suggestion and inserted a custom field at publication time (the API are really badly documented though).
Works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful!
If I may add something, the full syntax of changed is probably:

   `changed: function(newPost, oldPost) { [...]}`

Probably not very useful unless you want to log the changes though (I didn't needed it, but I logged all the parameters to understand what it was passing).

Comment: Good catch. That wasn't exactly it (http://docs.meteor.com/#observe_changes) but I updated the post from the API.